# How to disambiguate a function call in GCC C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, disambiguation

I get the following error warning:

```
reference to 'selectionMode' is ambiguous
candidates are: virtual KFile::SelectionMode KFileView::selectionMode() const
                virtual KFile::SelectionMode selectionMode() const;
```

The call is as follows:

```
    return KFileIconView::selectionMode();
```

How can I disambiguate the call so to refer to either the first or the second variant (I think the second is the correct one)?

**UPDATE:**

I currently fixed the build by replacing the call with the following: **return KFileIconView::KFileView::selectionMode();** I think this chooses the first candidate. How can I choose the second candidate if the first is the wrong one?

Comment: Could you show the code where these functions are declared?

Answer (score 2):

You have to  use the scope resolution operator to disambiguate those functions.

Calling KFileView::selection mode from outside the class:

```
KFileView view;
view.selectionMode();
```

`::selectionMode();` Used to call the global function from inside the KFileView implementation.

`KFileView::selectionMode();` Used to call the member function from inside the KFileView implementation.

Comment: With what should I replace the return line if I want the second candidate?

Comment: I totally do not understand this answer.

Comment: Does `KFileIconView` inherit from `KFileView`, and provide another implementation of the virtual function?

Comment: @Anixx  _'I totally do not understand this answer ...'_ At least your question is pretty unclear. [Improve it please](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24397021/edit)!!

Comment: @Sophit I do not know, possibly. What if this is the case?

Comment: It appears that `KFileView` and `KIconFileView` are Qt classes. Based on what I can see, you want to use code similar to the first snippet I pasted above. You need to instantiate one of these classes, and then call the member function via that instance. The function call can be in the return statement.

Comment: I currently fixed the build by replacing the call with the following: return KFileIconView::KFileView::selectionMode(); I think this chooses the first candidate. How can I choose the second candidate if the first is the wrong one?

Comment: Is your function trying to return a function pointer or a `KFile::SelectionMode`? The functions you're asking about are virtual member functions, but your code tries to call them without an instance.

Comment: I do not know, sorry.

Comment: Okay, it looks like you're thoroughly confused now. I suggest posting more of your code and perhaps someone can help you further.